# baker's and barber's in British English

Tags: british-english, dialect

The Longman Dictionary says "baker's" and "barber's" could mean their respective establishments in British English. If so, is the following OK?

> There is a two-storey **barber's** across the street.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is fine.  It is somewhat odd (why is the number of storeys relevant?), but there is no mistake.

Similarly "There is a dilapidated barber's down the street".  One of the main differences between "barber's" and "barbershop" is that the latter is primarily American.

Comment: Thank you. Do you find this odd too? "There is a two-storey barbershop across the street."

Comment: I'm comparing the difference, if any, between "barber's" and "barbershop."

Comment: In context, barber's can mean barbershop.  But not every contexts allows that.  Barbershop doesn't mean "of the barber" and you don't talk about a barber's quartet.

Comment: Thank you. So you mean my barbershop sentence sounds more natural than my "barber's" sentence?

Comment: "two storey barbershop" sounds equally odd.  You normally don't classify barber's/barbershops by their number of floors, as that is an irrelevant measure.

Comment: Do you have an adjective that applies to a barbershop but not a barber (the person)?

Comment: If we put that adjective in my sentence and the resulting sentence doesn't sound right, then we'll show "barber's" and "barbershop" do not mean the same.

Comment: The main difference between _barber's_ and _barbershop_ is that the latter is mainly American.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you find this okay? "There is a dilapidated barber's down the street"?

Comment: @James K: One situation I could see where a quality of the building would matter is when the place is being used as a reference, as part of a set of directions for example.

Comment: You mention British English and, as Michael says, _barbershop_ is American (Oxford says NORTH AMERICAN). You could say "I live on the High Street, opposite the barber's."

Comment: ...Or _barber's shop_ as two words.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir You're right, but it is a rare situation.  Barber's are nearly always on a single (ground) floor, since they depend so much on walk-in business. I did know one which had a basement (for men and children) and the ground floor (for (higher value) women.)  In locations where ground space is so valuable that a barbers would want to spread up, then the buildings would probably not be single business occupancy.  More likely there would be a barbershop on the ground floor and flats on the floors above, I'm not sure this is relavent.

Answer (score 1):

Sample: There is a two-storey barber's across the street.

No, **but not due to grammar.** Barber shops and bakeries are on the ground or first floor of a building.

They may be located on the ground or first floor of a two-storey building but they do not constitute a two-storey building.

I was at the barber's [shop] across the street this morning.

By the way, there is no difference with AmE in these cases.

Comment: The OP's sentence is highly contrived and as always the OP never explains why they created (or copied) a certain construction.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It sure is contrived as barber's are always on the ground floor and even if exceptionally one isn't, the likelihood of it being two storey is really slim.

Answer (score 0):

We Brits do this with a lot of professions which are also establishments.

Butcher's, baker's, candlestick maker's*, grocer's, doctor's, dentist's, tobacconist's, cobbler's, barber's, hairdresser's… the list goes on.
We would rarely add 'shop' to this. These can easily stand alone.

"I'm going to the doctor's next Tuesday" really describes the visit to the establishment rather than the person, though without further qualification one would expect their purpose would be to see the doctor.

*Just to complete the set with reference to the old nursery rhyme, [rub-a-dub-dub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rub-a-dub-dub) ;)